# How do I make a column DEFAULT(NULL) in SQLite.swift

Tags: swift, sqlite.swift

I'm trying to define my database structure, but I can't figure out how to set the default value of a column to `NULL`. This is what I want it to produce:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    content text DEFAULT(NULL),
);
```

I have the following code

```
let content = Expression<String?>("content")

try self.db.run(test.create { t in
    t.column(content, defaultValue: nil)
})
```

But `defaultValue: nil` obviously does not work. What do I set instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you create the column in the table with the `NOT NULL` qualifier, the column's default value is `NULL`. You don't need to do anything special to get the behavior you want.

```
CREATE TABLE test {
    content TEXT
};
```

Create the table that way. When you insert rows into that table, if you don't provide a specific value for the `content` column, the row will be added with no value (`NULL`) in that column.